# How would I call and store this information

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search-tree

I have a question that I think I know the answer to but I'm not too sure.

So I made this program, the following is the account class and the bank program that uses it

account class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.UUID;


public class Account {

double balance;

String name;

UUID AcctN;

int pin;


public void Account ()
{
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner sa = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Your starting balance is 0.0");
    double initBal = 0;
    balance = initBal;

    System.out.println ("Enter your full name");
    String owner = sa.nextLine();
    name = owner;

    UUID number = idOne;
    AcctN = number;

    System.out.println ("Enter your pin number containing ONLY 4 numbers");
    int pins = sc.nextInt();
    pin = pins;



}

public void withdraw (double amount)
{
    if (balance <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Insufficent funds");
    }
    else
    {
        balance -= amount;
    }


}



public void deposit (double amount)
{
    if (amount <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println ("You cannot deposit negative or 0 funds");
    }
    else
    {
        balance += amount;
    }


}

public void withdrawfee (double amount)
{

    if (balance <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Insufficent funds");
    }
    else
    {
        double fee = 10;
        balance -= amount + fee;
    }

}


public double getBalance ()
{
    return balance;
}
public String toString()
{
    return String.format ("User info: %s\n Balance: $%s\n Account Number: %s\n Pin Number: %s",     name, balance, AcctN, pin);
}
}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean quit = false;
    Account ACT = new Account ();



    do
    {
        System.out.println ("Welcome to the Bank\n\n***********\n 1: Create account\n 2: Check accounts\n 3: Withdraw funds\n 4: Withdraw with fee\n 5: Deposit funds\n 6: Quit");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        switch (input)
        {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println ("Make an account");
            ACT.Account();
            System.out.println ("Current information: ");
            System.out.println (ACT.toString());
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println (ACT.toString());
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println ("How much do you wish to withdraw?");
            ACT.withdraw(sc.nextDouble());
            System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println ("How much do you wish to withdraw?");
            ACT.withdrawfee(sc.nextDouble());
            System.out.println ("An additional 10 dollars has been deducted from your account");
            System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println ("How much do you wish to deposit");
            ACT.deposit(sc.nextDouble());
            System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
            break;
        case 6:
            quit = true;
            break;
        }

    }while(!quit);
    System.out.println ("Thank you for using the Bank..");

}

}
```

So the 'create account' works for one person and if I were to create it again then it would simply overwrite the name and balance.

So if I wanted to essentially store all of this information would I simply have to use an array? But then how would I be able to call each user and withdraw/deposit funds from those specific accounts.

I would think a Binary Search Tree might work but at the same time I'm not sure if a simple array list would be efficient?

To clarify I would want me to be able to

1) Call a specific user, probably would have to use a .contains() and I suppose that the contains should link to a specific and unique account ID.

2) Once it reaches that user, theyre able to use the switch menu as it is currently.

This is just a personal project to help better understand how Java works, not homework.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to keep it simple. We can just use an array list or list... or map. Since the order of accounts don't matter I would suggest a map. But since it looks like you are new to the java language it is better to work with Lists most of the time so I'll show you how to use a list.

There are other issues with the code... like it will only run once with one account. There is a lot to expand on. If you are really interested I can finish helping you with this easy project on skype @ yawang2247.

Otherwise the below will fix your current question. 
This should be your revised main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

ArrayList<Account> myList;

public static void main (String [] args)
{
myList = new ArrayList<ACT>(); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
boolean quit = false;
Account ACT = new Account ();



do
{
    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Bank\n\n***********\n 1: Create account\n 2: Check accounts\n 3: Withdraw funds\n 4: Withdraw with fee\n 5: Deposit funds\n 6: Quit");
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    switch (input)
    {
    case 1: 
    if(listContains(ACT.getAcctN())){
    // you need to make the above getAcctN() method in you Account.java
        System.out.println ("You already have an account!");
        break;
    }
        System.out.println ("Make an account");
        ACT.Account();
        System.out.println ("Current information: ");
        System.out.println (ACT.toString());
        myList.add(ACT);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println (ACT.toString());
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println ("How much do you wish to withdraw?");
        ACT.withdraw(sc.nextDouble());
        System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println ("How much do you wish to withdraw?");
        ACT.withdrawfee(sc.nextDouble());
        System.out.println ("An additional 10 dollars has been deducted from your account");
        System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println ("How much do you wish to deposit");
        ACT.deposit(sc.nextDouble());
        System.out.println ("Thank you for your service");
        break;
    case 6:
        quit = true;
        break;
    }

}while(!quit);
System.out.println ("Thank you for using the Bank..");

}
// below searches array for a particular account
public static boolean listContains(UUID accountNum) {
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if(myList.get(i).getAcctN() == accountNum) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 }
```